# Sending PIN-message in BlackBerry does not work

Tags: blackberry, java-me

My application sends PIN-messages, but when my application sends a PIN-message, it just arrives to outbox folder and remains there with clock icon. And it is not being sent really to the recipient.

Below there is my code, could you please tell me what is wrong with it:

```
public class SendPin implements carinfoResource
{
    private static ResourceBundle _res = 
       ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_ID, BUNDLE_NAME);

    public SendPin() {
    }

    public void sendPin(int command)
    {
        Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore();
        //retrieve the sent folder
        Folder[] folders = store.list(Folder.SENT);
        Folder sentfolder = folders[0];
        //create a new message and store it in the sent folder
        Message msg = new Message(sentfolder);
        PINAddress recipients[] = new PINAddress[1];
        try{
            //create a pin address with destination address of 20000000
            recipients[0]= new PINAddress("289A2FF6", "Soporte Desarrollo");
        }
        catch (AddressException ae)
        {
            System.err.println(ae);
        }

        try{
            //add the recipient list to the message
            msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients);
            //Command travel without troubles
            if(command == 0)
            {
                //set a subject for the message
                msg.setSubject(_res.getString(OKSUBJECT));
                //sets the body of the message
                msg.setContent(_res.getString(OKBODY));
            }
            else
            {
                //set a subject for the message
                msg.setSubject(_res.getString(ISSUESUBJECT));
                //sets the body of the message
                msg.setContent(_res.getString(ISSUEBODY)+"  "+this.getIMSI());
            }
            Transport.send(msg);
        }
        catch (MessagingException me)
        {
            System.err.println(me);
        }
    }

    public  String getIMSI() {
        String imsi = null;
        try {
            imsi = GPRSInfo.imeiToString(SIMCardInfo.getIMSI());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return imsi;
    }
}
```

Comment: make a simple app, as [is described here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Programmatically-send-a-PIN-message/ta-p/444958). And it should work. Then add more complexity to it, step by step.

Comment: Make sure you have BIS access . If not, the message will stay in outbox